# Why is my Regular Expression returning false?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've created a regular expression that validates the usable area codes for the state off Connecticut, I've tested various phone number strings against the regEx , all off which return true, yet when i implement it into my if else statement, it will return false. Even if its correct
Here is my code.

```
var string = '203-432-5917';
function phoneValidator() {
    
    let regEx = /^(203|408|860|959)[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/gm
    if(string=== regEx) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
```

and here is my test example that returns true

```
var string = '203-432-5917';
var regEx = /^(203|408|860|959)[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/gm
regEx.test(string);
```

Comment: what is `g.value` ? Also you are **NOT** using `.test` for reGex in your `if` condition! Thats why its returning `false` even though true! Feels like a `typo` only question to me!

Comment: You must use `if (regEx.test(g.value))` and declare the regex without any `gm` flags.

Comment: That is my fault,  i thought i had edited the string yesterday, the g.value was from the html side that i was trying to get it to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regEx.test(string) inside the if condition

```js
var string = '203-943-6347';

function phoneValidator() {
    let regEx = /^(203|408|860|959)[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}$/gm
    if(regEx.test(string)) {
        console.log(true)
    } else {
        console.log(false)
    }
}
phoneValidator();
```